# i use kotlin coroutines nullpointExecption but not show just crash no log

Tags: android, exception, kotlin-coroutines

i use kotlin coroutines encounter nullpointExecption but not show me just crashed no log to print 
i code like this:

```
  val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val files = File(path).listFiles(videoFileFilter)
                    Log.d("yanghua", "${files.size}")
                    for (file in files) {
                        Log.d("yanghua", file.absolutePath)
                    }


            }
```

the files is null because there no file matched,than files.size is nullpoint exception,but app crashed but not show me the exception,
and I use thread instead,it will be crash too but show me where the Exception,like this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.huayang.localplayer/com.huayang.localplayer.FileExplorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

I don't know why? Anybody knows?

Comment: your files  array is null .. when for loop check  files.length() it throw null point exception .. check you have all runtime permissions

Comment: i means it not show the Exception,just crash why?

Comment: why it show exception ???  You can not put try catch any where ????

Comment: have you given permission in manifest file like this?          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I write the exception on purpose!!

Comment: the AS not show me the exception when i use kotlin cortouries ,but use thread it will show me the exception,let me find the bug quickly,the kotlin has the bug?

Comment: Paste logs online somewhere.